Как убрать размытие в Python Arcade
Все текстуры в моей игре на arcade размыты, хотя графика должна быть пиксельной. как это исправить?
Код которым я загружаю текстуры
class Player(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("player.png")


def on_draw(self):
    self.my_sprite_list.draw(pixelated=True)

Можно прочитать об этом по ссылке (Edge Artifacts - Python Arcade 2.6.17)
